# I am facing some errors while installing Caffe on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, caffe

I am trying to install Caffe on a system running Ubuntu 14.04. When I run *make all*, it goes seemingly well till I face the error shown in the screenshot. Any help on resolving it would be much appreciated.

[image: Screenshot containing the error]

Comment: have you installed opencv?

Comment: Yes, I have installed OpenCV. I have OpenCV 2.4 on my system.

Comment: I googled for a solution to this, and I did find many people have having the same issues ( https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/1276). One of the solution asks us to add the following lines to the makefile _LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy \
  lmdb boost_system hdf5_hl hdf5 m \
  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs_ However, I don't find any lines resembling these in the make file.

Comment: look at [this line](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/Makefile#L173)

Comment: @Shai Thanks for the link!! I noticed that the makefile on the link is quite big, in terms of the number of lines. The makefile on my system is only 106 lines. Does this mean that there is an issue with my makefile. If so, what do I have do in order to rectify it?

Comment: What I mean is that the makefile on my system is incomplete.

Comment: how did you get caffe? did you clone it fro. github? what branch have you checked out?

Comment: I cloned it from github. I did not understand what you mean by  branch.

Comment: did you clone it from BVLC/caffe, or from NVIDIA/DIGITS? Have you clone from other source? a git repository many have several branches, make sure you are working with the master branch: `git checkout master` you should have code similar to that on the web. It's odd that your Makefile is not identical

Comment: I made a mistake while copying the Makefile.config.example file. I downloaded caffe again from the master branch.  When I run make all, there are no hitches. However, when I run make test, I get errors related to **test_layer_factory.cpp** and **test_upgrade_proto.cpp**. I get _undefined reference to boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)_

Comment: looks like a new question to me....